# Is it possible to set the titleTextAttributes of a UINavigationBar with the UIAppearance API?

Tags: objective-c, ios5

My app contains a UITabrBar which has a UINavigationController in every tab. Instead of setting the titleTextAttributes of all the navigation bars can I use the UIAppearance API?

Right now my code looks like

```
NSDictionary *textTitleOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor blackColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, [UIColor clearColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, 0, UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, nil];

navController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textTitleOptions;
bNavController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textTitleOptions;
meNavController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textTitleOptions;
```

I would like to do something like

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:navBarTintColor];
```

but there is no setTitleTextAttributes method.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Do you mean "textTitleOptions", rather than "navBarTintColor"?

Comment: BTW- tangental issue with your options dictionary. You should use `[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]` instead of just integer `0`. Otherwise, the compiler will treat the `0` like the sentinel `nil` and ignore everything after that parameter.

Answer (score 7):

The following works.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: textTitleOptions];
```

What happens when you try to run that code?